# Piechart overlay highcharts

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

have been trying to prevent this clustering but nothing is coming through. have tried overlays, distance, rotation but the labels are still clustering. How do i prevent them from overlapping?

[image]

```js
  <script>
    $(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Administration/Dashboard/PieChartDrilldown/0', function (data) {
            $('#container0').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'PARKING',
                    floating: true,
                    align: 'center',
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: </b>: Ksh. {point.y:,.0f}',
                },
                credits: false,
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        size: '100%',
                        padding: 0,
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        innerSize: '50%',
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            distance: -30,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 10,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: Ksh. {point.y:,.0f}',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Parking',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: data.data

                }]
                ,
                drilldown: {
                    series: data.drilldown
                }
            });
        });
        });
</script>
```

```html
    <div id="container0" class="col-md-3" style="margin:0px; height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: You can use [distance](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) parameter in combination with [connectors](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.connectorWidth).

Comment: when I put a positive distance some of the information on the label doesn't show its cut off.

Comment: Can you setup live demo of chart on the jsfiddle.net, with hardcoded data or attach your data.data variable?

Comment: @SebastianBochan will do that later